# como separo un csv de 500.000 filas en varios csv de 2000 filas c/u

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, csv

lo siguiente es que tengo un csv con muchas filas, y para poder procesarlas, tienen que estar en csv un poco mas pequeño, entre 1000 y 2000 filas.
Lo que he estado intentando es separar manualmente las filas llevando la cuenta, al principio funciono xq solo era una lista, ahora tengo mas de una lista y el proceso se retrasa xq me tardo separando los csv, gracias.

Comment: Hay una razon tecnica por la cual separar los archivos en 1000/2000 filas? Hasta donde se Excel puede manejar mas de 500 mil lineas.

Comment: por qué separas para procesarlas luego?

Comment: Tu mejor opción es una macro en Excel que te separe todo en archivos.

Comment: tengo 500.000 productos en excel para subir al import de magento2 y magento tiene un limite de 30.000, pero se tranca y es mejor subirlos de 1000 o 2000 para que se puedan subir mas rapido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas separar los archivos por filas (ten en cuenta que algunos CSV pueden tener celdas con contenido multi-linea que podria cortarse) puedes usar una herramienta que viene con **Git**.

Al [instalar Git para Windows](https://git-scm.com/download), se instala una herramienta *Git Bash* (linea de comandos de Git), que viene incluida con Git.

Use el comando `split` en Git Bash para dividir un archivo:

Por lineas: En el ejemplo, en archivos con 10000 líneas cada uno:

```
split myLargeFile.csv -l 10000
```

Tambien es posible por tamaño: en este ejemplo, en archivos de 500 MB cada uno

```
split myLargeFile.csv -b 500m
```

Para ejecutarlo en la carpeta donde estan los archivos CSV abre la carpeta en el explorador y haz click con el boton derecho para elejir "Git bash" y ejecutar alli el comando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]